# how to call function inside function in code igniter helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to access function inside function in code-igniter helper

Comment: function hello1(){ $this->hello2();} function hello2(){ echo 'hi';}

Answer (score 1):

you can use a helper function inside another function provided that you have loaded/extended that helper and the function you want to use is not private.
have you tried something like this:
**HELPER**

```
funtion helper1($var) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    /** you cannot use $this inside helper */

    // call another function 
    helper_function2();
}
```

helpers are global so you can use helper functions anywhere in you code as long as you have loaded the helper first. you can load your helper in the constructor of your controller: $this->load->helper('new_helper');

Answer (score 0):

You can use any functions in CI helpers. If you want to add a new function to an existing helper, you will have to extend that helper.

It's all in the manual: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers

Here's an excerpt from that link:

```
// any_in_array() is not in the Array Helper, so it defines a new function
function any_in_array($needle, $haystack)
{
    $needle = is_array($needle) ? $needle : array($needle);

    foreach ($needle as $item)
    {
            if (in_array($item, $haystack))
            {
                    return TRUE;
            }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

// random_element() is included in Array Helper, so it overrides the native function
function random_element($array)
{
    shuffle($array);
    return array_pop($array);
}
```